# Laravel 8 array callable syntax for 'uses' in route not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

```
Route::post('/update-client', 
    array(
        'uses' =>  'Client\API\ClientAPIController@Update', 
        'as'   =>  'apiUpdateClient',
    )
);

Route::post('/delete-client', 
    array(
        'uses' =>  'Client\API\ClientAPIController@Delete', 
        'as'   =>  'apiDeleteClient',
    )
);
```

But, these routes are not now working in Laravel 8. Below are error details

> Target class [Client\API\ClientAPIController] does not exist.

It works if I write like below and got it fixed

```
Route::post('/update-client', 
    array(
        'uses' =>  'App\Http\Controller\Client\API\ClientAPIController@Update', 
        'as'   =>  'apiUpdateClient',
    )
);
```

Question -

My route file contains many client routes. So, instead of appending App\Http\Controller with each route, I thought to do it like below,

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Client\API\ClientAPIController;

Route::post('/update-client', 
    array(
        'uses' =>  [ClientAPIController::class, 'Update'], 
        'as'   =>  'apiUpdateClient',
    )
);
```

Above code gave me error,,,

> ReflectionFunction::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string,
> array given

Am I using wrong syntax for uses parameter?

Comment: I saw the video. but they did not tell anything about uses and as parameter. can you suggest?

Comment: @lagbox: Question is more clarified now.

Comment: can you provide more of the stack trace for this current error

Comment: @lagbox: Please check my routes. They work fine in Laravel 7 but not working at all in Laravel 8. I fixed it by changing the code mentioned above. Now, can you suggest, how to can I initialize the class without using string syntax in `uses` param?

Comment: I see what you are talking about, it is not when registering the route, it is when actually dispatching to that route you get the error ... i will look into it more, might need to register an issue with laravel

Comment: I opened an issue for this: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/34451

Comment: They have closed this issues.  No. That syntax isn't supported. uses refers to an action which always needs to be a callable or Controller@method string.

Comment: @DeepeshThapa yes we can read ... I am sending in a PR to correct this

Comment: @lagbox  Did they not abandoned the use of 'use' in routes starting from laravel 8?

Comment: @DeepeshThapa no, just because it isn't explicitly in the documentation doesn't mean it doesn't exist, there are tons of things that are not in the documentation

Comment: Yes, but to use 'uses' in routes we have to explicitly modify the RouteServiceProviders from laravel 8. It is mentioned in the upgrade guide for laravel 8

Answer (score 6):

Just remove the '**uses**' as told in laravel documentation.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Client\API\ClientAPIController;

Route::get('/users', [ClientAPIController::class, 'Update']);
```

refer to this documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade

All of a sudden they changed the way we write laravel routes

Comment: My route contains `uses` and `as`. Do you want me to remove both?

Comment: Yes, but if you want to keep them you will need to manually update your RouteServiceProviders. Please watch this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfE1tnMG6fE&t=239s  mentioned on 8:45

Comment: There is nothing mentioned about the usage as I mentioned in my question. I saw the video already

Answer (score 2):

You have the use the new way:

```php
Route::post(
    '/update-client',
    [ClientAPIController::class, 'update']
)->name('apiUpdateClient');

Route::post(
    '/delete-client',
    [ClientAPIController::class, 'delete']
)->name('apiDeleteClient');
```

More info: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#named-routes